# Moneroaddress.org balance verification, wallet restoration, and usage precautions

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, mnemonic-seed, wallet-recovery

I have used the moneroaddress.org website to generate a wallet, sent some funds using shapeshift.io

I kept my spend and view key, my wallet address and mnemonic.

All this was done offline except for the trade

I later used xmr check site to see the transaction went through and my wallet address received those funds.

If I wish to see my wallet balance later and restore it, should I use simplewallet?

Do any precautions need to be taken?

Answer (score 3):

> If I wish to see my wallet balance later and restore it, should I use simplewallet?

Yes simplewallet is your best choice for restoring your wallet. Instructions to restore from mnemonic-seed can be found [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10/how-can-i-recover-a-wallet-using-the-mnemonic-seed). You can can also restore from [keys](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/55/if-i-saved-my-view-key-and-spend-key-can-i-recover-my-wallet-if-my-mnemonic-seed) but that is slightly more difficult.

Before restoration, the [xmr tests](http://xmr.llcoins.net/checktx.html) site you mentioned is the easiest way to verify your balance (assuming your mnemonic seed and keys were kept safe and no outgoing transactions occurred) with the use of your [view key](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/954/how-to-use-the-view-key-to-see-amount-sent-to-cold-storage) to see the incoming transactions.

> Do any precautions need to be taken?

You did the right thing by creating your wallet [offline](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/42/what-is-the-safest-method-to-create-a-monero-wallet-for-cold-storage)

Store your mnemonic-seed in a safe place offline. When restoring, ensure your system is free from keyloggers and you use a strong password.